# How to replace a space with a word while extract the data from PDF using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I want to replace any empty column with a word; for example, the word **BLK** while extract Pdf data.

the below tables are the example of the expected table and actual result.

Original Table

```
+--------------------------------------+
|# |NAME        |TEL        |GENDER    |
|---------------------------|----------|
|1 |JOHN        |096587498  |M         |
|2 |VILLA       |           |F         |
+--------------------------------------+
```

**Expected Result**

```
# NAME TEL GENDER
1 JOHN 096587498 M
2 VILLA BLK F
```

**Actual Result**

```
# NAME TEL GENDER
1 JOHN 096587498 M
2 VILLA F
```

The actual result is from the class **PDFTextStripper**.

capture of pdf
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately you did not share the pdf in question, so I cannot tell whether it is tagged. Can you share it for analysis?

Comment: @mkl you can access the example file here. https://drive.google.com/open?id=10ZkdPlGWzMJeahwnQPzE6V7s09d1nvwq

Comment: Ok. I'll try and look into that. Most likely not before Monday, though.

Comment: (I had a quick look. Your PDF is tagged. If it is representative of your source PDFs then extraction of the tagged text would help you.)

Answer (score 2):

The `PDFTextStripper` does not see the graphical lines in the PDF, it merely sees text characters. Thus, in your line #2 it sees "2", "Villa", and "F" with gaps in-between. With this class alone, therefore, you won't get what you want.

In general you have the following options using PDFBox:

- You can first try and recognize the table cell regions in your PDF by parsing the vector graphics instructions of the page and then extract text cell by cell.

  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51560024/1729265) provides a proof-of-concept for this. Beware: This answer focuses on the example document provided by the OP of that question. In particular it expects the lines to be drawn as thin filled rectangles; for a generic solution, the code collecting the table lines needs to be extended to also recognize lines drawn otherwise.

  This approach obviously requires table rows and columns to be divided by lines (or by extension alternatively by background colors or something similar); this is not always the case.

  In case of your example document the code works out of the box:

  ```
  [A1] # 

  [A2] Name 

  [A3] Tel 

  [A4] Gender 

  [B1] 1 

  [B2] John 

  [B3] 096875959 

  [B4] M 

  [C1] 2 

  [C2] Villa 

  [C3]  

  [C4] F
  ```

  *(output of [ExtractBoxedText](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/extract/ExtractBoxedText.java#L139) test `testExtractBoxedTextsTestWPhromma`)*
- You can extract the text attempting to reflect the layout of the PDF. If you know the general layout of the table in question (column n goes from here to there...), you can derive the table cell contents.

  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45842515/1729265) provides a proof-of-concept for the layout-aware text extraction. Beware, the code is PDFBox 1.8.x based, some adaptions might be necessary.

  This approach requires knowledge of the table column layout; this is not always given.

  In case of your example document the code works out of the box:

  ```
                   #              Name                                                            Tel                                    Gender
                   1              John                                                            096875959                              M
                   2              Villa                                                                                                  F
  ```

  *(output of [ExtractTextWithLayout](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox1/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox1/extract/ExtractTextWithLayout.java#L35) test `testExtractTestWPhromma`)*
- For tagged PDFs you can try to extract the text including the tagging which reflects the table structure (if properly tagged).

  As your example document is tagged, I'll show a quick & dirty proof-of-concept for this below.

  This approach requires the PDF to be properly tagged; this is not always the case.

#### Extraction of content with tags

If your PDF is properly tagged, you can extract the content including the markup tags like this:

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(SOURCE);

Map<PDPage, Map<Integer, PDMarkedContent>> markedContents = new HashMap<>();

for (PDPage page : document.getPages()) {
    PDFMarkedContentExtractor extractor = new PDFMarkedContentExtractor();
    extractor.processPage(page);

    Map<Integer, PDMarkedContent> theseMarkedContents = new HashMap<>();
    markedContents.put(page, theseMarkedContents);
    for (PDMarkedContent markedContent : extractor.getMarkedContents()) {
        theseMarkedContents.put(markedContent.getMCID(), markedContent);
    }
}

PDStructureNode root = document.getDocumentCatalog().getStructureTreeRoot();
showStructure(root, markedContents);
```

*([ExtractMarkedContent](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/extract/ExtractMarkedContent.java#L49) test `testExtractTestWPhromma`)*

using these two helper methods

```
void showStructure(PDStructureNode node, Map<PDPage, Map<Integer, PDMarkedContent>> markedContents) {
    String structType = null;
    PDPage page = null;
    if (node instanceof PDStructureElement) {
        PDStructureElement element = (PDStructureElement) node;
        structType = element.getStructureType();
        page = element.getPage();
    }
    Map<Integer, PDMarkedContent> theseMarkedContents = markedContents.get(page);
    System.out.printf("<%s>\n", structType);
    for (Object object : node.getKids()) {
        if (object instanceof COSArray) {
            for (COSBase base : (COSArray) object) {
                if (base instanceof COSDictionary) {
                    showStructure(PDStructureNode.create((COSDictionary) base), markedContents);
                } else if (base instanceof COSNumber) {
                    showContent(((COSNumber)base).intValue(), theseMarkedContents);
                } else {
                    System.out.printf("?%s\n", base);
                }
            }
        } else if (object instanceof PDStructureNode) {
            showStructure((PDStructureNode) object, markedContents);
        } else if (object instanceof Integer) {
            showContent((Integer)object, theseMarkedContents);
        } else {
            System.out.printf("?%s\n", object);
        }

    }
    System.out.printf("</%s>\n", structType);
}

void showContent(int mcid, Map<Integer, PDMarkedContent> theseMarkedContents) {
    PDMarkedContent markedContent = theseMarkedContents != null ? theseMarkedContents.get(mcid) : null;
    List<Object> contents = markedContent != null ? markedContent.getContents() : Collections.emptyList();
    StringBuilder textContent =  new StringBuilder();
    for (Object object : contents) {
        if (object instanceof TextPosition) {
            textContent.append(((TextPosition)object).getUnicode());
        } else {
            textContent.append("?" + object);
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("%s\n", textContent);
}
```

*([ExtractMarkedContent](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/extract/ExtractMarkedContent.java#L74) helper methods)*

The output for your example PDF

[image: enter link description here]

is

```
<null>
<Document>
<Table>
<THead>
<TR>
<TH>
<P>
# 
</P>
</TH>
<TH>
<P>
Name 
</P>
</TH>
<TH>
<P>
Tel 
</P>
</TH>
<TH>
<P>
Gender 
</P>
</TH>
</TR>
</THead>
<TBody>
<TR>
<TH>
<P>
1 
</P>
</TH>
<TD>
<P>
John 
</P>
</TD>
<TD>
<P>
096875959 
</P>
</TD>
<TD>
<P>
M 
</P>
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TH>
<P>
2 
</P>
</TH>
<TD>
<P>
Villa 
</P>
</TD>
<TD>
<P>

</P>
</TD>
<TD>
<P>
F 
</P>
</TD>
</TR>
</TBody>
</Table>
<P>

</P>
</Document>
</null>
```

You recognize the empty cell:

```
<TD>
<P>

</P>
</TD>
```

This proof-of-concept extracts to the standard output. You obviously can alternatively collect the data in a string builder or stream, or you can fill the `<Table>` data immediately into custom structures, they after all already come separated in cells.

**Beware**: This only is a proof-of-concept. Where the code outputs data like this `System.out.printf("?%s\n", ...);`, some specific handling may be required. Also other border conditions likely are not adequately considered. (Actually I only implemented it to properly extract the contents of your example PDF.)

Comment: ExtractMarkedContent has been tested with the current PDFBox 3.0.0 development branch SNAPSHOT. It should work, though, with the current 2.0.x releases, too.

Comment: Thank you very much man for your efforts. I will try these methods and see if they can solve my problems. So much appreciate :).