# extracting data by table/header using pdfbox

Tags: java, pdf, extract, pdfbox

I am trying to extract data from PDF by header/table. I am not sure if the PDF data is considered to be header or table. I tried to find if there are any metadata in the PDF, but it is null instead.

Here are the PDF examples:

I want to get the lists and amount of each list from the Summary Of Charges Header.
[image]

Based on the summary of charges, there are the amount and qty for each charges.
[image]

this is my code for the metadata which metadata variable comes out as null:

PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("invoice.pdf"));

```
    if(!document.isEncrypted()) {
        PDFTextStripper stripper  = new PDFTextStripper();
        stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
        String text = stripper.getText(document);
        
        PDDocumentInformation info = document.getDocumentInformation();
        PDDocumentCatalog catalog = document.getDocumentCatalog();
        PDMetadata metadata = catalog.getMetadata();
        InputStream stream = metadata.createInputStream();
    }
    document.close();`
```

and this code basically just give me chunks of texts.

PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("invoice.pdf"));

```
    if(!document.isEncrypted()) {
        PDFTextStripper stripper  = new PDFTextStripper();
        stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
        String text = stripper.getText(document);
        //InputStream stream = metadata.createInputStream();
        System.out.print("Text:" + text);
    }
    document.close();
```

Comment: Unless the pdf is properly tagged, there is no indication in the pdf about its structure, in particular what content is a table. Unfortunately tagging information in a PDF is optional. Thus, are your pdfs tagged properly?

Comment: i am not sure if my PDF is properly tagged. any way to check it ?

Comment: You can try using the code from the [ExtractMarkedContent](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/extract/ExtractMarkedContent.java) test, e.g. test method `testExtractTestWPhromma` with helper method `showContent`. If that code outputs something usable, the your PDF seems tagged in a usable way. That was code for [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54983991/1729265) in the section titled "Extraction of content with tags".