# Extracting text from pdf (java using pdfbox library) from a tables with merged cells

Tags: java, pdfbox

Inspired by discussion [Extracting text from pdf (java using pdfbox library) from a table's rows with different heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51380677/extracting-text-from-pdf-java-using-pdfbox-library-from-a-tables-rows-with-di)
I'm able to perfectly read "normal" tables. Kudos to [mkl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1729265/mkl).

The issue is that I cannot figure out how to read data from tables where text is merged from few cells.
I will still continue my brainstorming, but if somebody has idea how we can improve code from mkl in class
[PdfBoxFinder](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/extract/PdfBoxFinder.java#L54) to allow processing of tables with merged cells I would appreciate.
I will definitely provide solution here if I find myself.
Thanks to all in advance.

I was trying to find merged cells based on text, but it is not very effective. This approach generates to many types of tables. I'm looking for more generic solution.
I will be trying to check of x positions of texts, but I'm not there yet.
Demo if available on GitHub [Demo](https://github.com/pdob-git/testarea-pdfbox2/tree/Pdob-stack_78001237)

Example files are:
Merged cells https://github.com/pdob-git/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/Pdob-stack_78001237/pl.pdob.input/merged_cells_example.pdf
Regular tables https://github.com/pdob-git/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/Pdob-stack_78001237/pl.pdob.input/regular_table.pdf

Result how code currently recognizes tables is show in following files:
Merged cells https://github.com/pdob-git/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/Pdob-stack_78001237/pl.pdob.results/merged_cells_example.pdf-rectangles.pdf

Regular tables https://github.com/pdob-git/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/Pdob-stack_78001237/pl.pdob.results/regular_table.pdf-rectangles.pdf

Regular Tables are recognized correctly, but issue is with merged cells.
Document with merged bottom row:
[image: Source file for merged cells]

Is recognized as regular table - bottom row has 3 cells and should have one
[image: Result file for merged cells]

Demo code:

```java
package pl.pdob.pdfTables;

import mkl.testarea.pdfbox2.extract.PdfBoxFinder;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Class to demonstrate issue with tables with merged cells<br>
 * <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78001237/extracting-text-from-pdf-java-using-pdfbox-library-from-a-tables-with-merged-c">
 * Extracting text from pdf (java using pdfbox library) from a tables with merged cells
 * </a>
 * <br>
 * Method Drawing found rectangles taken from {@link mkl.testarea.pdfbox2.extract.ExtractBoxedText}<br>
 * and modified
 */
public class Stack78001237 {


    private static final File RESULT_FOLDER = new File("pl.pdob.results");

    private static final File INPUT_FOLDER = new File("pl.pdob.input");

    private static final String EXAMPLE_PDF = "regular_table.pdf";
//    private static final String EXAMPLE_PDF = "merged_cells_example.pdf";


    static {

        if (!INPUT_FOLDER.exists()) {
            //noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
            INPUT_FOLDER.mkdirs();
        }

        if (!RESULT_FOLDER.exists()) {
            //noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
            RESULT_FOLDER.mkdirs();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Stack78001237 stack78001237 = new Stack78001237();
        stack78001237.drawBoxes(EXAMPLE_PDF);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("SameParameterValue")
    private void drawBoxes(String fileName) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(INPUT_FOLDER, fileName);

        try (
             PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file) ) {
            for (PDPage page : document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages()) {
                PdfBoxFinder boxFinder = new PdfBoxFinder(page);
                boxFinder.processPage(page);

                try (PDPageContentStream canvas = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true, true)) {
                    canvas.setStrokingColor(Color.RED);
                    for (Rectangle2D rectangle : boxFinder.getBoxes().values()) {
                        canvas.addRect((float)rectangle.getX(), (float)rectangle.getY(), (float)rectangle.getWidth(), (float)rectangle.getHeight());
                    }
                    canvas.stroke();
                }
            }
            document.save(new File(RESULT_FOLDER, fileName + "-rectangles.pdf"));
        }
    }
}
```

[Stack78001237.java](https://github.com/pdob-git/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/Pdob-stack_78001237/src/main/java/pl/pdob/pdfTables/Stack78001237.java)

The issue is that file [PdfBoxFinder.java](https://github.com/pdob-git/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/Pdob-stack_78001237/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/extract/PdfBoxFinder.java) works perfectly, but only with regular tables.
I'm currently digging how to solve it. If I knew, solution I would not bother stackoverflow community with such question.

Comment: Original question has been edited. Supporting GitHub repo has been created. There are examples and screen shots. In opinion it is detailed enough and I would like to ask to open it again.
If I find solution, I will share.

Comment: I just took a look at the `PdfBoxFinder` class. Currently it is processing the retrieved lines by determining the **x** coordinates of vertical lines and **y** coordinates of horizontal lines (`processThinRectangle`) and building a grid from these coordinates (`getBoxes`). For your requirements you need a different approach, for example in `processThinRectangle` you can instead collect the full lines (maybe separating horizontal from vertical ones) and in `getBoxes` you can create boxes from them.

Comment: Beware, though, in your example there are many short line pieces: to identify the box of the merged cell, you'll have to recognize that its top border is not a single line but consists of multiple line segments one after the other. And the most annoying detail is that there even are tiny gaps sometimes between the segments building a single line; they are so small that you won't see them in renderings, maybe they even have a width of 0 in the float representation of common PDF viewers but your Java floats or doubles will see a positive difference..

Comment: In general you'll additionally have to be prepared for longer lines forming the combined edges of multiple cells in a row or column. Furthermore, table borders may also be drawn stroking cell sized rectangles or stroking regular lines, and sometimes even Bézier curves for rounded corners.

Comment: @mkl Thank you for reply. I have done something similar that you are describing. See answer below. If you like it, I can create pull request and contribute to your wonderful work on PDFBox examples.

Comment: If you would like to see your code there, feel free to start a pr. I may change some comments, adding some references to the related solution etc.

Comment: Ok. I will let you know when I do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue.
The approach is similar to original solution and have following steps:

- read thin rectangles which are forming table borders
- segregate horizontal and vertical ones, remove duplicates and sort
- merge similar lines to have one line from the top to bottom and from left to right where possible
- read boxes formed by lines.

Demo is in files:
[MainDemo.java](https://github.com/pdob-git/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/main/java/pl/pdob/pdftables/MainDemo.java)
[ExtractBoxedTextMergedCellsTest.java](https://github.com/pdob-git/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/pl/pdob/pdftables/ExtractBoxedTextMergedCellsTest.java)