# Is it possible to fetch graphs from pdf using pdfBox

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I have a pdf file which includes graphs, not in image format. Is there any way to process pdf file using content streams and fetch graphs out of it

Comment: Your question is about `pdfbox`, so why tag `itext`?

Comment: I was unsure about it, seems linked with pdf creation extraction. that why I used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pdfbox 2.0.2 > Calling of PageDrawer.processPage method caught exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38931422/pdfbox-2-0-2-calling-of-pagedrawer-processpage-method-caught-exceptions) - see the answer, it shows how to collect lines.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, I'm new in manipulating pdf objects, can you guide how it is related? I need only graphs that are present in pdf, not anything else like table, text, image.

Comment: There is no such concept as a "graph" in PDF. The answer I linked to describes how to collect line coordinates. So if your graph is vector graphic within a table, you'll end up with the table and the graph details and will have to sort it out.