# Extract "Graphic" Line positions with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am currently working on a little java application to transform some PDF bound data and I am using PDFBox for this. The pdf itself is very simple and just contains some headers and a table which seperates rows with a line. I am trying to find the coordinates of this line so that I can dynamically extract by area as some rows vary with their height. I have not really found any information on this during my search as almost all results deal with "text lines" and not actual lines. Is this even possible with PDFBox or will I have to look for another pdf library.

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This finds lines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38931422/pdfbox-2-0-2-calling-of-pagedrawer-processpage-method-caught-exceptions However there is no guarantee that your table is made of lines.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thank you that is exactly what I was looking for